# Removing string characters form mysqli database and utilize two variables derived from database

Tags: php, mysqli

Good Day

Can anyone please just help me in the right direction with PhP and mysqli function ?

I have the following in a field called 'speed' in my database: 10240k/10240k.The first 10240k is the Upload speed and the second 10240k is the Download speed. Now I need to remove the 'k' the '/' and the last 'k'. then I need to devide the first by 1024 to get Mb and the same with the second.

Please help me in the right direction to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first explode on the basis of "/" then you can substr(string,0,-1) to remove the last character from the string. After getting both upload speed and download speed you can convert them into Mb. I didn't convert it into Mb because you did not mention it is Kb or GB?

```
    <?php
$str = "10240k/10240k";
$str = explode("/",$str);
$UploadSpeed = substr($str[0], 0, -1);
$DownloadSpeed = substr($str[1], 0, -1);

?>
```

Comment: @JacquesEngelbrecht please approve the answer if your problem is solved.